Anchor pass parameters to PDA creation from initialization
I'm getting crazy on passing a parameter to the seed of a PDA. That's the simplified program:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("JAe3BFznJPTWu4JF1x1JQwzJ29b9jZJ9gPANJTdY2qUf");

#[program]
pub mod test {
    use super::*;

    pub fn init(ctx: Context<Create>, value: i64) -> Result<()> {
        let account: &mut Account<MyAccount> = &mut ctx.accounts.account;
        account.value = value;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(value: i64)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [&value.to_be_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = from,
        space = 8 + 8
    )]
    pub account: Account<'info, MyAccount>,
    
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Signer<'info>,
    
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct MyAccount {
    pub value: i64,
}

And this is the ts test code:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor"
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor"
import { expect } from "chai"
import { Test } from "../target/types/test"

describe("test-program", () => {
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
    anchor.setProvider(provider)

    const program = anchor.workspace.Test as Program<Test>

    const wallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from([<my-private-key]));

    it("Is initialized!", async () => {
        const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
        buffer.writeBigInt64BE(BigInt(10), 0);

        const [ testPDA ] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [buffer],
            program.programId
        );

        const tx = await program.methods
            .init(new anchor.BN(10))
            .accounts({ from: wallet.publicKey })
            .signers([ wallet ])
            .rpc();

        const account = await program.myAccount.test.fetch(testPDA);
        expect(account.value.toNumber()).to.equal(10);
    })
})


I want to initialize the seed of the PDA with the value passed to the init function with seeds = [&value.to_be_bytes()] however I get the error:
Error: AnchorError caused by account: escrow. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: G68d8LuAHcP5AUPiQW9M3Tq1WQxnFmWCBBF5eE3kqrH2
Program log: Right:
Program log: 4CvHcVVmVNFouFwb2gxrodiY9Xt5jTUEt2USDvFgYbmh

Instead, if I set the seed as seeds = [&10_i64.to_be_bytes()] it perfectly works!
What am I doing wrong?
Is the tag #[instruction(value: i64)] not doing what I think?
This is getting me crazy!
EDIT:
tried to print on chain with msg!("{:?}", value.to_le_bytes()); and with msg!("{:?}", 10_u64.to_le_bytes()); and they both result in: [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
I repeat thath with 10_u64.to_le_bytes() the test works!
Client side I always pass the buffer which prints <Buffer 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>. Thus it seems everything correct!
Everythings is making me think that the code #[instruction(value: i64)] is passing a wrong value

I think bn is little endian.
I just tried it in a progam and this works:
Try in the client:
const extraSeeds = new anchor.BN(10).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8);

const [playerPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
  [Buffer.from("player"), payer.publicKey.toBuffer(), extraSeeds],
  program.programId
); 

let tx = await program.methods
        .initPlayer(gameDataSeed, new anchor.BN(10))
        .accounts({
          player: playerPDA,
          gameData: gameDataPDA,
          signer: payer.publicKey,
          systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc({ skipPreflight: false });

and in the program:
    pub fn init_player(
        ctx: Context<InitPlayer>,
        _level_seed: String,
        extra_seed: i64,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        init_player::init_player(ctx)
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(level_seed: String, extra_seed: i64)]
pub struct InitPlayer<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 1000, // 8+32+x+1+8+8+8 But taking 1000 to have space to expand easily.
        seeds = [b"player".as_ref(), signer.key().as_ref(), extra_seed.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub player: Account<'info, PlayerData>,


Here is an example using a u32:
https://github.com/brimigs/solana-payroll/blob/main/anchor/programs/payroll/src/lib.rs
And one using u8:
https://github.com/Woody4618/colosseum_2024/blob/main/blobs/program/programs/blobs/src/instructions/attack_blob.rs
So in general the instruction field does the right thing its just the the client and program seeds result in different bytes. You could try print the buffer in the client and in the program instruction and look at the bytes to see whats going on.

Thank you for the hint and the answer but the code you route is not valid since the init function needs a i64 and not a buffer.
I updated the question with the prints results

Oh yeah i was thinking to use the buffer to derive the PDA but pass in the Bn as you already did and then change in the program also to le_

Yes i tried with le also and the problem remains

I just tried it in a program and it works. I added the example code i just tried.

Sorry but I think your code is incomplete. PlayerData is not defined and the line init_player::init_player(ctx) gives this error: failed to resolve: function 'init_player' is not a crate or module

erm yes its not the whole code, just showing the important parts about using a i64 instruction data as seeds. Should i add the whole code?

Well not the whole code but at least the minimum to let it compile would be helpful form me thank you
